# Correlation between Variables and Graph

Tags: graph, correlation

I have two nodes: A and B. They are strongly correlated. Another node C is strongly correlated with node B. Can we confirm that node C will also be correlated with node A?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "strongly correlated nodes". Nodes can either be connected or not, what is the meaning of correlation in this context?

And more general: correlation is at most transitive AFAIK. Thus, having the relation `R` and nodes `a,b,c` it follows that

```
aRb and bRc => aRc
```